# Rails disable options with `grouped_options_for_select` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm generating a group of options by passing a hash of strings to Rails' `grouped_options_for_select` helper method. I'd like to disable some of the options, but there's doesn't seem to be an official way of achieving this because grouped_options_for_select doesn't take a `disabled:` hash unlike other helper methods such as `options_for_select`. Is there a way of somehow bypassing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having gone through rails source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/246f07c7512eca59fb304162b1b1d7dea5eb6e64/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb), it turns out that the way to pass disabled parameters is the following:

```
grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, {selected: [11, 12], disabled: [14, 15]})
```

where 11, 12, 14, 15 are record ids.